# Not able to compile Qt Project - Qt Speech

Tags: c++, qt, compilation, qml, speech-recognition

I am trying to compile the project present at [Link](https://github.com/qt/qtspeech/tree/wip/speech-recognition/examples/speech/qmlspeech)

While compiling from the main folder I am getting the error:

```bash
:-1: error: Project ERROR: qtspeech/examples/speech/qmlspeech/qmlspeech.pro is lacking an install target.
```

I tried adding following text in the `qmlspeech.pro` file:

```cpp
target.path += /home/harshmittal/build
INSTALLS += target
```

I got the following error:

```bash
:-1: error: Project ERROR: /qtspeech/examples/speech/qmlspeech/qmlspeech.pro installs target to unexpected location.
```

If I try to open the project Individually and try to compile it, I receive the following error:

```bash
:-1: error: Project ERROR: You cannot build examples inside the Qt source tree, except as part of a proper Qt build.
```

I want to compile this project, original youtube link: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYQHk-KNI6I)

Qt Version: 5.15
OS: Linux

Comment: Please provide more details - Qt version, OS, etc.

Comment: @folibis I have added the details. Qt version: 5.15 and OS is Linux.